# add two values together in a class to form another string

Tags: c#, class

simple one here, that ive simply forgot, i lost the code i used it on yesterday. the code is hopefully self explanatory

currently fullname doesnt work...

Thanks guys!

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Forename { get; set; }
public string Surname { get; set; }
public string Username { get; set; }
public string Dept { get; set; }
public string JobTitle { get; set; }
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
public string Office { get; set; }

public string Fullname { get; set{Fullname + "" + Surname };}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a cople of problems here. Firstly `get` is used to return some value, and `set` is used to *set* value, so you got it reversed. Secondly you need to `return` something from `get`. Thirdly it looks like you don't really want to use `set`.

I think that you meant:

```
public string Fullname { get { return Forename + " " + Surname; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in the get method....

Comment: Cant see why anyone would down mark this answer when its correct.

Comment: I haven't downvoted it, but it would not work if the code would be **just** moved to `get`. `return` is missing and `;` is in wrong place.

Comment: True, I was a bit fast to answer here. But the main Problem should have been cleared by the Response. Anyway - there are better replies than mine so I won't care too much, right?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you want to do is this:

```
public string Fullname { get { return Forename + "" + Surname; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public string Fullname { get { return Forename + " " + Surname; } }
```